# How to input a number x and print it x times, increasing by 2 each time

Tags: python

I need to take number x as input and print the first x odd numbers. If input 8 was given, the output would be: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15.

Comment: What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: So... Whats the question?

Comment: Hint: you will need a loop (either a for-loop or a while-loop) to advance your number and use either a strategic value to increase it or an if statement to only print the values that meet your condition

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = int(input('Enter your number:'))
for i in range(2*x):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        print(i)
```

Comment: This helped me, I got it now. I didn't understand how to print x amount of times but I see now it is (2*x). Thank you

Comment: Can I ask why the range is 2*x?

Comment: since you are skipping every 2 numbers, you need to loop through double the amount of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without loop. It uses `range` to get directly the even numbers, converts those integers to string and displays them all at once using newlines as separator:

```
n = int(input('Enter your number:'))
print('\n'.join(map(str,range(1,2*n,2))))
```

output for 8 as input:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
```